# How java thread will going to work in below scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify, thread-synchronization

Suppose in multi-threaded environment there are 5 threads t1,t2,t3,t4,t5.... Thread t1,t2,t3,t4 calls the wait() method (inside synchronized  block) and only Thread t5 calls notify() method then which thread going to get priority to again acquire the lock in critical section.

Comment: Have you read the [Javadoc for `o.notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())? I think that the third sentence answers your question.

Comment: When `o.notify()` is called, a thread waiting on that object's monitor (if there is any) will be woken up. Note that you could still have some race conditions though; and eg. call notify() on an object before any thread calls wait() on it..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why don't you try writing and running the code? :)

Answer (score 1):

The choice is arbitrary and any one of the 4 threads may be woken up. The intrinsic lock in java is not fair which will cause some of the waiting threads to wait longer than others even though they attempted to gain the lock first. A [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) can be used to grant access to the longest waiting thread if this matters for your program.